# Visual Studio Run Starts First Project Instead of Startup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#

In my solution, I have four projects. When I select the Release configuration and click on Run (or hit <kbd>F5</kbd>), it starts the first project in the solution list rather than the one I've set as the startup project. I've already tried the following:

- Cleaned and rebuilt all projects
- Restarted Visual Studio
- Restarted PC
- Set a different project as the startup project, and then set it back to the one I want
- Verified in the solution properties that it is set to run the active project and not the "selected one".
- Tried setting the solution properties to run the "selected project" and selected the project I want and hit Run.
- Verified in the Configuration Manager that the Build check box for all of the projects is selected for both Release and Debug configurations.

Note that it works fine when I select the Debug build...